# Change state of parent component from Child component by extending the class

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Before marking it as an duplicate read the question completely.**

I have two component, say `A` and `B`. `A` extends `React.Component` and `B` extends `A`. Calling `super` inside the `constructor` of `B` will make all the things available under `this` of `A` to be available under `B` also.

The issue I'm facing is, I've a method which will updated the state of `A`. I'm calling this method from `B`. This still updates the state of `B` not `A`. Is this expected or am I doing anything wrong.

**Working example**

```js
class A extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.updatedState = this.updatedState.bind(this) //bound to this parent
    this.state = {
      text: 'Hello from the other side!'
    }
  }
  
  updatedState(){
    this.setState({
      text: 'I must have called a thousand times!'
    })
  }
  
  render(){
    return <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
  }
}

class B extends A{
  constructor(){
    super()
  }
  
  render(){
    return <div>
      <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
      <button onClick={this.updatedState}>Update state</button>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <A/>
    <B/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Another Example**

This is not using the `constructor` or the `super`. I instantiate `A` using `new` and call the methods. The method is being called but the render is not triggered.

```js
class A extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.updatedState = this.updatedState.bind(this) //bound to this parent
    this.state = {
      text: 'Hello from the other side!'
    }
  }
  
  updatedState(){
    console.log('called')
    this.setState({
      text: 'I must have called a thousand times!'
    })
  }
  
  render(){
    return <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
  }
}

class B extends A{
  render(){
    var parent = new A() 
    return <div>
      <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
      <button onClick={parent.updatedState}>Update state</button>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <A/>
    <B/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Of course this is expected. The `<A />` has nothing to do with `<B />`. They are completely separate component instances

Comment: @AndrewLi I understand that! It's because `super` will run the `constructor` of the parent and everything inside the parent's constructor will be created as a new copy for the extended class. Is that ryt?

Comment: What do you mean *created as a new copy for the extended class*?

Comment: New copy of the contents inside the parent's constructor.

Comment: You mean a new instance? When `A` is rendered, it's a new instance. When `B` is rendered, it is also a new instance. The instances have no relationship, even if the classes they are instances of have one.

Comment: No when `B` extends `A`, a new copy/instance  of all the contents inside `A`'s constructor will be created under  `B`'s context when we use `super` under `B`'s constructor.

Comment: yeah, and what's the question?

Comment: How to change the state of the parent class from child. I child extends from parent.

Comment: You already have... `B` changes state of `A` onClick does it not?

Comment: LOL. It's not. Try the example. Only the `B` component's text is changed on `onClick`

Comment: Yeah? The parent's state *is* being changed on click...

Comment: Exactly. Then why the render of the parent is not called when the state is changed. That's my question.

Comment: Ohh, I understand what you're saying now, I was confused at what you were getting at.

Comment: @AndrewLi Added another example. This is not using the constructor or the super. I instantiate `A` using `new` and call the methods. The method is being called but the render is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example does not work as it supposed to.

```
class B extends A{
  render(){
    var parent = new A() 
    return <div>
      <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
      <button onClick={parent.updatedState}>Update state</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

In the above there is a B object which extends A.

Assuming that this instance of B references adress 0x001 in memory.

var parent =new A() creates an A object and it references another address in memory  for example 0x002. This reference is kept in memory which is reserved for instance of  object B extends A. that's it. they have just Has - a realationship. But B extends A (B is A ) so they have is-a relationship.

http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php

Comment: Thanks. But, Isn't this supposed to be a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: And Whatever the instance be the render is not getting called. My second example works till calling the updatestate.

Comment: Add a constructor and call super

Comment: that's the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Extending B with A doesn't link any new instance of B with a new instance of A. Furthermore, try composition instead of inheritance. There is no specific use case in inheritance that composition doesn't cover. Composition is more natural, more easier to reason, behavior is more explicit and also a lot safer.

Here's how I would do it with composition. I don't know what exactly your use case is, so pardon me if the following refactored example doesn't fit in with what you're trying to accomplish. But nevertheless, you should be able to achieve the same with composition instead of having to use inheritance.

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <h1>{this.props.displayText}</h1>
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  state = {
    displayText: 'Hello from the other side!'
  }
  
  updateState () {
    let displayText = 'I must have called a thousand times!';
    this.setState({
      displayText: displayText
    }, () => this.props.onUpdateClick(displayText));
  }
  
  render () {
    return <div>
      <h1>{this.state.displayText}</h1>
      <button onClick={this.updateState.bind(this)}>Update state</button>
    </div>
  }
}

class C extends React.Component {
  state = {
    displayTextA: 'Hello from the other side!'
  }
  
  changeA (value) {
    this.setState({
      displayTextA: value
    });
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <A displayText={this.state.displayTextA} />
        <B onUpdateClick={this.changeA.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <C/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here are a few posts that you might find helpful:-

- [Composition vs Inheritance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)
- [Mixins Are Dead. Long Live Composition](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.gpvmike69)

Comment: But, we need to write another component `C` to achieve this. I know that how `composition` works. I'm just curious if there's any other way because we use a word called `class` and `extends`.

Comment: You could checkout [Stateless functional components](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components). Classes in React do provide a simple and familiar syntax for inheriting/extending React's lifecycle methods, but all the benefits OOP promised to provide are no longer true. See [Goodbye, Object Oriented Programming](https://medium.com/@cscalfani/goodbye-object-oriented-programming-a59cda4c0e53#.vrxey5sc9).

Comment: stateless components are pure components in which you can't have states and React's lifecycle methods won't work. The truth is, we are not defining an class while writing React. It's a sugar coated way of writing React with ES6 syntax.